# Error comando Scanner Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, scanner

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar y me sale este error cuando ejecuto el comando Scanner alguien tiene idea de lo que pasa? Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: Para una mejor visualización el código y el texto del error deben ir el formato texto en lugar de una captura de pantalla por favor. ;)

Comment: Hola! Procura compartir código y errores como texto para que otros podamos leer y replicar los problemas. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3):

**Solución manual**: importar este paquete en la línea 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

**Solución automática**: Pon el cursor al final de la palabra Scanner i aprieta CONTROL+ESPACIO.

Ésto te soluciona el problema automáticamente y te importa el paquete en el sitio que toca.

Saludos!

Comment: Ya lo había hecho así con esa linea (import java.util.Scanner;) y me tiraba exactamente el mismo error, pero habia agregado esa linea manualmente, estaba en el lugar que corresponde, ahora lo hice con el control+espacio y finalmente funciono, tenes idea de porque? Muchas gracias!

Comment: la S de scanner con mayúscula, la doble n... depende. Si lo escribes manual hay mil maneras de errar. Control+espacio nunca falla :)

Comment: acepta la respuesta para cerrar pregunta si se ha resulto correctamente